How can I change date format from 2024-05-31 to 31/05/2024 after the data is read from an SQL query through an R Markdown file
Below is what I have attempted, however the data is still appearing as 2024-04-01.
The purpose of this code is to produce a line chart from two different data sets. One read from an SQL query and the other read from an excel file.
I have also tried to use SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT(Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS Date as the query but R is still storing the date in the wrong format.
# SECTION 4 - sql connection for reading old ticker data

# establish a connection to the sql server
connection <-
  dbConnect(
    odbc::odbc(),
    Driver = "SQL Server",
    Server = "server1",
    Database = "a_Team",
    Trusted_Connection = "Yes"
  )

# declare parameters to improve reusability of code
schema_name <- "ins"
table_name <- "Info_USD Swap Rate Data"
start_date <- "2024-04-01"
end_date <- "2024-07-31"
column1 <- "USD_1M"
database_name <- "a_Team"

#  sql query to retrieve data using established parameters
query1 <-
  paste0(
    "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 103) AS Date, ",
    column1,
    " FROM ",
    database_name,
    ".",
    schema_name,
    ".  [",
    table_name,
    "] WHERE Date Between'",
    start_date,
    "' AND '",
    end_date,
    "' AND ",
    column1,
    " IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY Date"
  )



# store the retrieved data as variables under the secure connection
query1Details = dbGetQuery(connection, query1) 
query1Details <- dbGetQuery(connection, query1) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))


# close the connection
dbDisconnect(connection)

and this is how I plot the line chart
    # SECTION 6 - ggplot 2 chart construction

# define color scheme for sources
source_colours <-
  c("#1f78b4",
    "#1f78b4",
    "#1f78bd",
    "#33a02c",
    "#33a02c",
    "#33a02c")


# creates a faceted line plot using ggplot2
line_chart_plots <- ggplot(plot_data,
                           aes(
                             x = Date,
                             y = Rate,
                             color = Index,
                             group = interaction(Index, Source)
                           )) +
  geom_line(size = .5) + # add line plots
  facet_wrap( ~ Plot, ncol = 3) + #facet the plots into 3 rows
  labs(
    # remove axis titles and legend title
    title.position = "top",
    title = "",
    x = NULL,
    y = NULL,
    color = ""
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 8, face = "bold"),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 7, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 9),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.box = "horizontal",
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.3, 'cm'),
    legend.spacing.y = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
    panel.spacing = unit(1.5, "lines")
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = source_colours) + # apply custom colors
 
  ylim(0, 6) # sets y axis limits

# convert ggplot to an interactive plot using plotly and arrange legend
interactive_plot <- ggplotly(line_chart_plots) %>%
  layout(
    legend = list(
      orientation = "h",
      x = 0.5,
      xanchor = "auto",
      y = -0.1,
      traceorder = "normal",
      itemsizing = "constant",
      itemwidt = 80,
      valign = "bottom",
      nrows = 1
    )
  )

# renders the interactive plot
interactive_plot


That is how R stores Date. You could format, paste, coerce to character, but the right way to do this is to change the axes labels of your plot. How do you plot it?

Dates in R are in a single format. You can change the format to whatever you want, but then dates become just text. It's the same with percents: 50% is just a text representation for the number 0.5, not an actual numeric value.

@Friede I have updated the question to include the ggplot code.

Dates in both SQL Server and R are binary values, they have no format. Trying to change the format in SQL Server can only result in incorrect dates or errors, because the R date value has no format either. You can easily end up changing 4/7 to 7/4. Replace CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 103) with just Date and remove mutate(Date = as.Date(.... Then format the axis labels.
